# Delete Function using .filter Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, require

I am creating a note taking app and am getting stuck on my deleteNote function. I am needing to use the .filter method to remove notes w/ an assigned id and keep the ones not associated to that id. Here is my code so far.

```
const fs = require("fs"); 
const util = require("util");
// returns a unique ID for our returns 
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");

// creates a promified version of fs.readfile and writefile
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readfile); 
const writeFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.writefile);

class Store {
    read() {
        return readFileAsync("./db/db.json", "utf8");
    }
    write(note) {
        return writeFileAsync("./db/db.json", JSON.stringify(note)); 
    }
    getNotes() {
        return this.read().then(notes => {
            let parsedNotes; 
        try {parsedNotes = [].concat(JSON.parse(notes))}
        catch (err) {
            parsedNotes = [];
        }
        return parsedNotes;
        })
    }
// example of destructuring -- im taking the title, text string and destructuring it to add a unique id. 
    addNote(note) {
        const {title, text} = note;
        const newNote = {title, text, id: uuidv1()};
        return this.getNotes()
        .then(notes => [...notes, newNote]);
        .then(updatedNotes => this.write(updatedNotes));
        .then(() => newNote);
    } 

// delete note is going to take in an id and use a .filter to only keep the notes that do not include that id. 

    deleteNote() {
        
    }

} 

module.exports = new Store();
```

Answer (score 3):

You already know you're filtering, so just do it:

```js
deleteNote(id) {
    return this.getNotes()
        .then(notes => notes.filter(note => note.id !== id))
        .then(updatedNotes => this.write(updatedNotes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one which includes returning deleted note.

```js
  async deleteNote(id) {
    const notes = await this.getNotes();
    const filtered = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id);
    await this.write(filtered);
    const deleted = notes.filter((note) => note.id === id);
    return deleted;
  }
```